# Preventing JS from being load using JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, shopify

Right now I have a shop set up on Shopify, and Im using an app which installs on our store. This apps calls a script like so:

```
if(!add_to_order_tag)
$('.product_rp_div.p{{ product.id }}').append('<script async class="add_to_order" src="https://ro.boldapps.net/recurring_settings/add_to_order?&shop_url={{ shop.permanent_domain }}&group_id='+group_id+'&customer_id={{ customer.id }}&product_id='+prodId+'&variant_id='+myVariant+'"></'+''+'script>');
```

This script contains a call to `bootstrap.modal.min.js`, function which is already loaded onto my shop via the normal `bootstrap.min.js` and it is giving me trouble cause all my modals open and close really fast. since this script has important functions for the app to work but it only repeats the load of a script which I already have I was wondering if there was a way of preventing the second `boostrap.modal.min.js` from being loaded using JS? Or if there was a good work around to prevent the modal closing.

Here is my version of bootstrap being called:

```
//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/t/12/assets/bootstrap.min.css?7437598206705920800
```

And here is their version of the bootstrap model being called:

```
https://ro.boldapps.net/app_assets/js/bootstrap-modal.min.js
```

Thanks in advance for the help :D

Comment: Is it loading a different version of the same code, causing this problem? How much control do you have over the app load? Could you put some code around it?

Comment: The code which is on top calls the JS on the apps servers. So I cant touch that code. I can however add js before that call to prevent someway the loading of that specific js, if its possible. And the loading of that code is causing the problem cause the bootstrap modal functions are being loaded twice. If I take out that specific line, the modals work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One way of avoiding this somewhat tiresome behaviour, which does occur sometimes with third party apps, libraries or add-ons, is to simply reassign the relevant module while the library is loaded, then put it back afterwards. It's not beautiful, but it often works:

```
var bootstrap-temp = Bootstrap.Modal;
loadIrritatingLibrary();
Bootstrap.Modal = bootstrap-temp;
```

That will at least put it back in the right state at the end of the call.

Unfortunately Bootstrap ties itself into the `jQuery` module so it is harder to separate out - the actual jQuery modal function is stored at `jQuery.fn.modal` but given that much of the module is hidden, you may need to load in Bootstrap after the other script is loaded in.

Both of these work because the version of the code that JavaScript sees is the last version that was loaded in, so if you assign the same variable repeatedly it will remember the last one and that functions can be treated as variables in the same way that objects are.

A better solution where possible is to use a module loader like `RequireJS`, which should ensure everything is only loaded once, but that isn't always available in this kind of situation.

This also depends on the problem being the version of Modal being reloaded rather than something in that script affecting the way modals are drawn, which from your description could also be the problem. It should be possible to check the version being loaded in by the app to confirm whether there is a problem associated with that.

Comment: The Bootstrap.Modal is an object or what is that?

Comment: Edited with a bit more explanation. Unfortunately with jQuery plugins this is a little harder to do...